# Monitoring life time of a process

Tags: shell

I have a python script called hdsr_writer.py. I can launch this script in shell by calling

```
"python hdsr_writer.py 1234"
```

where 1234 is a parameter.

I made a shell script to increase the number and execute the python script with the number every 1 second

```
for param from 1 to 100000
    python hdsr_writer.py $param &
    sleep (1)
```

Usually, the python script executes its task within 0.5 second. However, there are times at which the python script gets stuck and resides in the system for longer than 30 seconds. I don't want that. So I would like to monitor life time of each python process executed. If it has stayed for longer than 2 second it would be killed and re-executed 2 times at most.

Note: I would like do this in the shell script not python script because I could not change the python script.

**Update: More explainations about my question**

Please note that: launching a new python process and monitoring python processes are independent jobs. Launching job doesn't care how many python processes are running and how "old" they are, just calls "python hdsr_writer.py $param &" every 1 second after increasing param. On the other hand, monitoring job periodically checks life time of all hdsr_writer python processes. If one has resided more than 2 second in memory, kills it, and re-runs it at most of 2 times.

Comment: You can use the [`timeout`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html) command for this sort of thing. Though you'll need to write the retry logic yourself.

Comment: Can u clarify: you want run all this script simultaneously in background ant then look for script with some particular parameter $param, and if this script stuck - give it 2 more chances?

Comment: For example I have a shell script called launch.sh that launches the python script one by one every 1 second, like this: at time t run "python hdsr_writer.py 13", at time t+1 run "python hdsr_writer.py 14", and so on. And I might have another shell script called "monitor.sh", this checks if there is any the python script is stuck. If there is one, kill it, restart it with exactly the same parameter. Maybe I can combine two these shell scripts in to one.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of sleep and nohup commands. After sleep time use kill to finish the execution of python script. You can check if the process is running with ps command.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

for param from {1..100000}
    nohup python hdsr_writer.py $param &
    pid=$!
    sleep(2)
    if [ ps -p $pid ]
    then
        kill -9 $pid
    fi
done
```

Re-answer:

I'd use two scripts, the first one (script1.ksh):

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

for param from {1..1000000}
    nohup script2.sh $param &
done
```

And the second (script2.ksh):

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

for i from {1..3}
   python hsdr_write.py $1 &
   pid=$!
   sleep(2)
   if [ ps -p $pid ]
   then
      kill -9 $pid
   else
      echo 'Finalizado'$1 >> log.txt
      return
   fi
done
```

The first script will launch all yours processes one after the other. The second one will check his own python process.

Comment: theoretically during `sleep 2` system can run another script with same PID=$pid. And you will kill WRONG script. no?

Comment: ps whitout parameters only list processes of the current terminal. But with -p I think you are right. In any case, you could use

ps -ef | grep 'hdsr_writer.py' | grep $pid

Comment: I would not like to wait for a python process to be finished before calling the next python script. Please see my update in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Not so short answer

```
#/bin/bash

param=1
while [[ $param -lt 100000 ]]; do
    echo "param=$param"
    chances=3
    while [[ $chances -gt 0 ]]; do
        python tst.py $param &
        sleep 2
        if [[ "$(jobs | grep 'Running')" == "" ]]; then
            chances=0
        else
            kill -9 $(jobs -l | awk '{print $2}')
            chances=$(($chances-1))
            if [[ $chances -gt 0 ]]; then
                echo "one more chance for parameter $param"
            fi
        fi
    done
    param=$(($param+1))
done
```

**UPD**
This is another answer as requested by OP. 
Here is still 2 scripts in one. But they can be spitted in two files.

Please pay attention that `$() &` is used to run sub-shells in background

```
#!/bin/bash

# Script launcher

pscript='rand.py'

for param in {1..10}
do
  # start background sub-shell, where python with $param is started
  echo $(
         left=3
         error_on_exit=1
         # go if any chances left and previous run exits not with code 0 
         while [[ ( ( $left -gt 0 ) && ( $error_on_exit -ne 0 ) ) ]]; do
            left=$(($left-1))
            echo "param=$param; chances left $left  "
            # run python and grab python exit code (=0 if ok)
            python $pscript $param
            error_on_exit=$?
         done
        ) &
done

# Script controller
# just kills python processes older than 2 seconds
# exits after no python left
# $(...) & can be removed if this code goes to separate script

$(while [[ $(ps | grep -v 'grep' |  grep -c python ) != "0" ]]
  do 
   sleep 0.5
   killall -9 -q --older-than 2s python
done) &
```

Comment: This script would wait and re-try until a python process has successfully processed before calling the next python script. That means, the next python call with 'param + 1' would not be executed until the python process with 'param' is finished. Please see my update in the question.

Comment: @duong_dajgja Pls take a look